# The phrase: I got told off

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage, sentence-structure, usage

Today I've come across a phrase and now I'm at a loss and confused a little bit.

It was:

- I don't cook sushi because I got told off I was trying once.

It sounds very "English" and for a non-native speaker is a little bit unusual.

It is usual and common for you?

Or would you say the same thing in another way?

Also, can you explain me, why ***do*** we have " I got" rather than to have "I was told off", please?

(or: Can you explain me, why we have "I got" rather than to have "I was told off", please?)

Thank you!

Comment: Yeas, you are right. There are virtually two questions here. The second one is about the question "can you explain me...". What's the variant more appropriate?

Comment: Your example is ungrammatical. Are you sure you stated it correctly?

Comment: Mmm, it's possible that I'm mistaken. Can I share the link when I came across this phrase here? (It's a podcast.)

Comment: _Told off_ is a colloquial way of saying _reprimanded_, and using _got_ rather than _was_ makes it even more informal. Should it perhaps read '_when_ I was trying once'?

Comment: @Kate Bunting Yeas, it could be with "when". It was really fast and difficult to understand. Can you also say a little bit about the change "got" and "was". When can we say so and when we can't, please?

Comment: The get passive https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/the-passive-voice-with-get-/4839624.html

Comment: *I don't cook sushi because I got told off **for** trying once* (or ***...when I tried***). But normally we'd move adverbial ***once*** there to immediately before the relevant verb *(**got told off**)* - *...I once got told off for trying*.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to say it is

> I don't cook sushi because i got told off the first time i tried.

also:

> "Got" is a common daily-English usage in these cases. It means the same thing as using "was". While fine in daily speech, it would not do in formal writing or a formal presentation.

So you can use 'got' or 'was' it does not really matter